# how to avoid clutch billiard balls?

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm working on the simple behaviour of billiard balls in a collision with each other. All works normal, but there was a problem when facing a few easy balls is the effect of coupling balls and they're cool with each other. Tell me how to prevent this.

```
bool MGBilliard::CollisingBall(CCPoint curr_point, CCPoint next_point)
{
    float dx = next_point.x - (curr_point.x + dvdt.x);
    float dy = next_point.y - (curr_point.y - dvdt.y);
    float d = dx*dx+dy*dy;
    return d <= BALL_RADIUS * BALL_RADIUS;
}
double MGBilliard::angleCollisionBalls(Ball* current, Ball* next)
{
    double na;
    double dx = fabs(next->location.x - current->location.x);
    double dy = fabs(next->location.y - current->location.y);
    na = atan(fabs(dy/dx));
    if(atan(fabs(current->location.y/current->location.x)) < atan(fabs(next->location.y/next->location.x)))
        na = current->angle - na;
    else if(atan(fabs(current->location.y/current->location.x)) > atan(fabs(next->location.y/next->location.x)))
        na = current->angle + na;
    return na;
}
for(unsigned int i = 0;i<BALL_COUNT;++i)
    {
        if(vBalls[i]->speed > 0){
            vBalls[i]->speed += vBalls[i]->acceleration;
            float dsdt = vBalls[i]->speed*dt;
            dvdt.x = dsdt*cos(vBalls[i]->angle);
            dvdt.y = dsdt*sin(vBalls[i]->angle);
            vBalls[i]->location.x += dvdt.x;
            vBalls[i]->location.y += dvdt.y;
            for(unsigned int j = 1; j < BALL_COUNT; ++j)
            {
                if(i == j) continue;
                if(CollisingBall(vBalls[i]->spriteBall->getPosition(),vBalls[j]->spriteBall->getPosition()))
                {
                    vBalls[j]->speed = 600;
                    double angle;
                    angle = angleCollisionBalls(vBalls[i],vBalls[j]);
                    vBalls[i]->angle = (float)-angle;
                    vBalls[j]->angle = (float)angle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to clarify this. What exactly is the behavior you see? What do you expect to happen instead? What have you been able to narrow this down to?

Comment: When the ball hits the ball the other, then there is grip balls and they whirl around and scatter corresponds to the wrong side in that need. This effect occurs when the face a few balls. It is expected that they have to face, and fly away to the opposite corners.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that rather than colliding, they actually stick together?

Comment: Look at this bit: `vBalls[i]->angle = (float)-angle; vBalls[j]->angle = (float)angle;` and have a think about what happens when `angle` is zero. This is only one bug, and does not explain all the issues you are seeing.

Comment: "Tell me how to prevent this" - Yes sir. In a minute. I'm on it.

Comment: @sehe easy there tiger; the guy is clearly translating from a foreign language and not doing brilliantly. I don't think you can reasonably infer the tone of the request given how much has been lost in translation.

Comment: @Rook Communication is letting each other know how you received a message, among other things

Comment: @sehe and how well do you think the nuances of your response will translate?

Comment: Humor works well when communication is difficult

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two straightforward bugs that spring to my attention with a quick look at your code.

Firstly, this:

```
vBalls[i]->angle = (float)-angle; 
vBalls[j]->angle = (float)angle;
```

is not the correct way to calculate opposing angles. For example, it will not do what you want it to do when `angle` is zero (or 180 degrees, for that matter).

Secondly, you iterate over your whole `vBalls` array multiple times, once with the index `i` and an inner loop with the index `j`. This means collisions will be calculated twice, and the `speed` of both balls would be set to 600! Changing your inner loop to be this:

```
for(unsigned int j = i + 1; j < BALL_COUNT; ++j)
```

should prevent this occurring.

There's also a more subtle bug. Your collision detection does not take into account time. Each ball moves a particular distance each iteration of your game loop. This means that if a collision does not occur in one 'tick', a ball could pass *straight through another ball* and then trigger the collision code *on the far side of the ball*. You cannot do a simple radius-based collision test in this situation, as if a ball moves more than (BALL_RADIUS * BALL_RADIUS) in a single step, your system will behave strangely or not work at all.

I personally would use vectors to describe speed and direction for each ball rather than angles and speeds, but refactoring your code to do this is a bit outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks I've refactoring my code, to use vectors,I think it will be easier than with the angles.